# Adjusting parallism based on number of partitions assigned in Consumer.committablePartitionedSource

Tags: java, akka-stream, alpakka

I am trying to use `Consumer.committablePartitionedSource()` and creating stream per partition as shown below

```
    public void setup() {
        control = Consumer.committablePartitionedSource(consumerSettings,
                Subscriptions.topics("chat").withPartitionAssignmentHandler(new PartitionAssignmentListener()))
                .mapAsyncUnordered(Integer.MAX_VALUE, pair -> setupSource(pair, committerSettings))
                .toMat(Sink.ignore(), Consumer::createDrainingControl)
                .run(Materializer.matFromSystem(actorSystem));
    }

    private CompletionStage<Done> setupSource(Pair<TopicPartition, Source<ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage<String, String>, NotUsed>> pair, CommitterSettings committerSettings) {
        LOGGER.info("SETTING UP PARTITION-{} SOURCE", pair.first().partition());
        return pair.second().mapAsync(16, msg -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> consumeMessage(msg), actorSystem.dispatcher())
                .thenApply(param -> msg.committableOffset()))
                .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(ex -> Supervision.restart()))
                .runWith(Committer.sink(committerSettings), Materializer.matFromSystem(actorSystem));
    }
```

While setting up the source per partition I am using parallelism which I want to change based on no of partitions assigned to the node. That I can do that in the first assignment of partitions to the node. But as new nodes join the cluster assigned partitions are revoked and assigned. This time stream not emitting already existing partitions(due to kafka cooperative rebalancing protocol) to reconfigure parallelism.

Here I am sharing the same dispatcher across all sources and if I keep the same parallelism on rebalancing I feel the fair chance to each partition message processing is not possible. Am I correct? Please correct me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to have a fixed parallelism across dynamically changing number of `Source`s that come and go as Kafka is rebalancing topic partitions.

Have a look at first example in the Alpakka Kafka documentation [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/consumer.html#source-per-partition). It can be adjusted to your example like this:

```java
 Consumer.DrainingControl<Done> control =
      Consumer.committablePartitionedSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("chat"))
              .wireTap(p -> LOGGER.info("SETTING UP PARTITION-{} SOURCE", p.first().partition()))
              .flatMapMerge(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Pair::second)
              .mapAsync(
                16,
                msg -> CompletableFuture
                         .supplyAsync(() -> consumeMessage(msg),
                                      actorSystem.dispatcher())
                         .thenApply(param -> msg.committableOffset()))
              .withAttributes(
                ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(
                  ex -> Supervision.restart()))
              .toMat(Committer.sink(committerSettings), Consumer::createDrainingControl)
              .run(Materializer.matFromSystem(actorSystem));
```

So basically the `Consumer.committablePartitionedSource()` will emit a `Source` anytime Kafka assigns partition to this consumer and will terminate such `Source` when previously assigned partition is rebalanced and taken away from this consumer.

The `flatMapMerge` will take those `Source`s and merge the messages they output.

All those messages will compete in the `mapAsync` stage to get processed. The fairness of this competing is really down to the `flatMapMerge` above that should give equal chance for all the `Source`s to emit their messages. Regardless of how many `Source`s are outputing messages, they will all share a fixed parallelism here, which I believe is what you're after.

All those messages eventually get to the `Commiter.sink` that handles offset committing.

Comment: Wow! It's clear and let me play around to see how this goes with my experimenting approach. Thank You for such detailed explanation